# Cannot select grade from different table with mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a question would like to ask you, it was about database (mysql).
I am doing a student management system , and I have stuck with some query, I would like to select grade_point and grade_name from table grade which according to mark in table exam, so my expectation is that if mark in table exam are between  grade_mark_from and grade_mark_up it will return grade_name and grade_point, you can see my table below.

Table grade :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|grade_id|grade_name|grade_point|grade_mark_from|grade_mark_up|comment         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1       |A+        |5          |80             |100          |Very good result|
|2       |A         |4          |70             |79           |Good result     |
|3       |B+        |3.5        |60             |69           |Good result     |
|4       |B         |3          |50             |59           |Good            |
|5       |C         |2          |40             |49           |Good            |
|1       |D         |2.5        |30             |39           |Good            |
|1       |E         |1.5        |1              |33           |No good         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table exam :

```
----------------------------------------------------
|exam_id|mark|comment|exam_id|subject_id|student_id|
----------------------------------------------------
|1      |50  | no    |1      |1         |1         |
|2      |30  | no    |1      |1         |2         |
|3      |70  | no    |1      |1         |3         |
|4      |90  | no    |1      |2         |1         |
|5      |60  | no    |1      |2         |2         |
|6      |25  | no    |1      |2         |3         |
----------------------------------------------------
```

so I have no idea to do it, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example let's say you would like the values for exam 3.

You can use BETWEEN:

```
SELECT grade_point, grade_name FROM grade, exam 
WHERE mark BETWEEN grade_mark_from AND grade_mark_up AND exam_id = 3;
```

or you can use single conditions:

```
SELECT grade_point, grade_name FROM grade, exam 
WHERE mark > grade_mark_from AND mark < grade_mark_up AND exam_id = 3
```